# Derivate w.r.t angle of an integral w.r.t radius

Tags: integration

I have a problem of this form:
$$ g(\theta; s, R) = \int_0^R \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} s(\rho \cos(\theta),\rho \sin(\theta))\ d \rho, $$
with $s$ an arbitrary derivable 2-D function.
I tried to develop it into:
$$ g(\theta; s, R) = \int_0^R  \rho\ \vec \nabla s(\rho \cos(\theta),\rho \sin(\theta)) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -\sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\ d \rho, $$

but from there I am stuck. I tried to look into complex analysis as well (treat it as a complex exponential) but I didn't find anything useful.

My question at this point is if we can simplify this expression more without the knowledge of $s$ and if we can ideally express $g$ only in function of $s$ (and not in function of its gradient) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you write the first variable of $s$ as $x$ and the second as $y$, you do have something along the line $-\partial_x s(x, y)\sin(\theta) + \partial_y s(x, y) \cos(\theta)$. Does this help?

Comment: It gives back the scalar product with the gradient right ?

Comment: Yes, only with a more understandable notation, at least to me